# Mysql join three tables and group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I've 3 tables.

```
 1. users (id,name,createdAt)

 2. images (id,createdAt)

 3. points_logs (id,createdAt,collectedAmount)
```

From these 3 tables I want to generate a report like this

```
Date       | NumberOfUsers | NumberOfImages | AmountCollected
2019-09-13 | 3             | 2              | 200
2019-09-14 | 4             | 3              | 300
2019-09-15 | 5             | 6              | 400
```

I've found this query by stackoverflow answer

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        u.newUsers, i.newImages, u.createdAt
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        COUNT(*) AS newUsers, DATE(createdAt) AS createdAt
    FROM
        users
    GROUP BY DATE(createdAt)) u
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
        COUNT(*) AS newImages, DATE(createdAt) AS createdAt
    FROM
        images
    GROUP BY DATE(createdAt)) i ON i.createdAt = u.createdAt) final
ORDER BY final.createdAt
```

This is for only two tables. How can I join the `points_logs` table to this?

I am using `Server version: 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu)`

Comment: Is there a problem with adding another join that you haven't mentioned?

Comment: why you've asked another question whereas it could be asked in the same Question

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you truly want to select all dates [in a particular range]. For each of those dates, you want to query some data from various tables.

I would suggest creating a query that gets you those dates first. Then you could use subqueries to get the corresponding data from your tables. If you want to exclude empty dates, you can use `HAVING` at the end.

How might you get the dates? Technically they're kind of constants, so there may be a smart way to get them without using any table, to the effect of `SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 ...`, except not *that* simple.

Or you might start with a query that simply retrieves the distinct dates from your tables. `UNION` a set of subqueries that select *only* the date column from their respective tables:

```
# Get all distinct dates across the tables
SELECT DISTINCT createdAt FROM users
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT createdAt FROM images
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT createdAt FROM points_logs
ORDER BY createdAt
;
```